# Why is the returned array of the function always a empty array?

Tags: arrays, c

Been working on a leetcode problem that should be simple but can't seem to find the error in my code. The idea is that given a array of integers called nums and a target number, I am to fill a int* array with the 2 indexes of nums that sum up to that target integer.

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize) {
    int* arrInd = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        for (int counter = i + 1; counter < numsSize; counter++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[counter] == target) {
                arrInd[0] = i;
                arrInd[1] = counter;
                return arrInd;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

However, when running a testcase of [2, 7, 11, 15] with the target of 9, the correct returned array should be
[0, 1] but my code is always returning []. Someone please explain.

Comment: Are you expected to store a value in the `returnSize` pointer?

Comment: Besides adding the statement `*returnSize = 2;` to the function you should probably use 
    `for (int i = 0; i < numsSize - 1; i++) {` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {`

Comment: leetcode is not a recommended place to learn a programming language, or programming in general.

Answer (score 2):

The leetcode testbed is almost certainly assuming you will store the size of the returned array in `*returnSize`. Since you don't, and it's presumably pre-zeroed, it thinks the array is empty no matter what you put in it (because C dynamically allocated arrays have no concept of their own size that can be queried with any public API, you *must* pass around both a pointer to the array and the size).

Just add:

```
*returnSize = 2;
```

immediately before `return arrInd;`.

Also, just to avoid a memory leak on failure, add `free(arrInd);` immediately before `return NULL;`.

Comment: Do you know what this *returnSize means? I don't see it anywhere else in the function so why does this matter for the output?

Comment: This is a very basic question. Do not try to learn C via Leetcode. Rather get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @NoobCoder: `int *returnSize` in the prototype means the function expects a pointer to `int`. Technically, this could mean it was input data, output data, or both, and either a single `int` pointed to or an entire array, so I'm deducing from context/variable name that it's intended to be where you *tell* the caller how much of the returned array is meaningful. The caller likely declared `int arraySize = 0;`, then passed `&arraySize` as the `returnSize` argument. When the function returns, they then read `arraySize` elements from the returned pointer.